# Random default value for a related model Django

Tags: python, django

I got a model Car  and model Bumper related to Car .  How can I set the default value of a Bumper's car to a random Car object in Django ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function:

```
from random import randrange

def random_car():
    n = Car.objects.count()
    return Car.objects.all()[randrange(n)]

class Bumper(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=random_car)
```

That being said, I'm not sure that using a random `Car` is a good idea. Often you want the things that create/change/delete the entities to be *deterministic*. By making things randomized, you make it harder to debug, analyze, etc. the code flow.

Comment: I tried a similiar version to yours but with random.choice(), and the problem is that Django recalculates the random value only once for each migrations. Moreover it will recalculate the random value each time a makemigrations command is entered infinitelly, so this doesn't seem to be a working example

Comment: @kenshin: well you likely *called* the method in the default, but you should not do that, you should specify `default=random_car` so *without* the brackets. Using `choice` is also a problematic approach, because that will load all the `Car`s into memory, and thus eventually, if the number of `Car`s increase, it will exhaust memory.

Comment: @kenshin: if you write `default=random_car()`, then of course it will *call* the function when interpreting the class, and save the *result* of the function, and this will indeed only randomize when you start the server. But if you pass a callable, Django will call it each time if it has to generate a random item.

Comment: so basically the randomizing action has to be taken out of Django, and be generated before the call hits the api.

Comment: @kenshin: you pass to the `default=...` a *reference* to a function, not the *result* of a function. The logic in the fields is that it will call the function. If that function each time provides a different value, then each time a different value will be used.